# Proof that $J_{\nu}(x) \sim (x/2)^\nu / \Gamma(\nu+1) \; \text{as} \; \nu \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, special-functions

I'm working through the exercises of Bender and Orszag's famous book, but I got stuck in *6.25 (a)*, in which it is asked to prove that

$$J_\nu (x) \sim (x/2)^\nu / \Gamma(\nu+1) \; \text{as} \; \nu \rightarrow \infty,$$

by using the following integral representation

$$J_\nu(x)=\frac{(x/2)^\nu}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\nu+1/2)} \int^\pi_0 \cos(x\cos\theta) \sin^{2\nu}\theta \, d\theta,$$

which is valid for $\nu > -1/2.$ ($J_\nu(x)$ is the $\nu$th-order Bessel function of the first kind.)

As the exercise belongs to section 6.4, which deals with Laplace's method and Watson's lemma, I thought I first had to perform a change of variables in order to get an integral of the form

$$I(x)=\int^b_a f(t)e^{x\phi(t)} \, dt.$$

So, I took $t=\cos\theta$ and obtained

$$\frac{(x/2)^\nu}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\nu+1/2)} \int^{1}_{-1} (1-t^2)^{p-\frac{1}{2}} e^{ixt} \, dt.$$

However, I cannot apply either Laplace's method or Watson's lemma, because the function $\phi$ I got is complex: $\phi(t)=it$.

What am I missing?

Comment: A suggestion based on a large amount of ignorance: Can you consider the real and imaginary parts
separately?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't think it makes anything easier as I would end up with $I(x)=\int^b_a f(t)\cos(xt) dt$ and again I would not be able to apply either Laplace's method or Watson's lemma.

Comment: For reference, the large $\nu$ behavior is $x^\nu/\left(\sqrt{\nu}2^{\nu}\Gamma(\nu+1/2)\right)$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, are you sure? where did you get that from? I'm just asking because your expression contradicts the point of the exercise.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  I calculated it using the Laplace method and then verified it numerically.  As the answer below indicates, there must have been a typo in the statement of the exercise.  If you'd like I can write up a short answer with some details of the calculation.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, I'd be really grateful if you could do that! I've seen this result in more than one place, for example in "A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions" by G. N. Watson, which should be the bible of Bessel functions.

Comment: Which page in Watson?

Comment: Oh gosh, I just realized that $\sqrt{\nu} \Gamma(\nu+1/2) \sim \Gamma(\nu + 1)$, so what I've written matches your statement!

Comment: that's nice, because I was having a hard time trying to find the expression in Watson's book :)
can you please still write an answer on how you got your result?

Comment: To expand on Random Variable's (now deleted) method, consider what $\sin^{2\nu} \theta$ looks like on the interval $[0,\pi]$ as $\nu \to \infty$.  It becomes a spike centered at $\theta = \pi/2$, so the values of the integrand away from $\theta = \pi/2$ shouldn't contribute much to the integral.  Consequently, we should be able to replace the rest of the integrand (namely $\cos(x\cos\theta)$) with its behavior near $\theta = \pi/2$ (namely $1$).

Comment: @AntonioVargas It deserved to be deleted.  It answered the wrong question.  But thanks for explaining how it could have been modified.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, Antonio.

@RandomVariable, it's a pitty I can't accept two answers because, if you corrected yours according to Antonio's idea, I'd also accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin, rewrite the integral as

$$
\int_0^\pi \cos(x\cos \theta) \exp\Bigl[2\nu \log \sin \theta\Bigr]\,d\theta.
$$

The quantity $\log \sin \theta$ has a maximum at $\theta = \pi/2$, and near there

$$
\log\sin\theta = -\frac{1}{2} \left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 + \cdots.
$$

Further

$$
\cos(x\cos\theta) = 1 + \cdots
$$

there, so by the Laplace method we have

$$
\int_0^\pi \cos(x\cos \theta) \exp\Bigl[2\nu \log \sin \theta\Bigr]\,d\theta \sim \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1\cdot \exp\left[-2\nu \cdot \frac{1}{2} \left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2\right]\,d\theta
$$

for large $\nu$.  Now simplify.

Comment: the secret is always in the first step! thanks a lot, Antonio.